# Why isn't Parchhayee black?

Tags: tv, captain-vyom

In *Captain Vyom* TV series, all of the Parajeevs (English: Parasites) of 7th Dimension are black. Actually, this blackness has been emphasized a lot. Black ink flows in their body instead of blood. Their planet's name is *Kaalikh* (English: Soot). Even their Sun is black.

But, the daughter of Emperor *Kaala Saaya* (English: Black Shadow), Parchhayee (English: Reflection) isn't black.

(You can see in the beginning and on 10:58)

Why is she not black?

Comment: I have translated the names because translated version appears in the subtitle.

Comment: Black like a dark human skin color (i.e. really brown) or like the night sky?

Comment: @Adamant Black like night sky.. Watch the video.

Comment: For me the bigger question is why they've got that guy wearing a comedy moustache. Did their budget not run to one that looks even vaguely realistic?

Comment: I watched 2 minutes of this before I suffered a Badness Register Overflow and I didn't see anything vaguely realistic at all.